# How do i get a Success message when i send a string as a input parameter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am sending a string as a input parameter and i should get a "SUCCESS" Message as my output in the postman collection...

This is my DAL.

```
 public class ResponseDAL
    {
        public static DataTable ResponseMessage(string Message)
        {
            DataTable dtMessage = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection myConnectionGroupData = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand myCommandGroupData = new SqlCommand("", myConnectionGroupData))
                    {
                        myCommandGroupData.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        myCommandGroupData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Option", " ");
                        myCommandGroupData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Message", Message );
                        myCommandGroupData.CommandTimeout = 0;
                        myConnectionGroupData.Open();

                        SqlDataAdapter sdaCategory = new SqlDataAdapter(myCommandGroupData);
                        sdaCategory.Fill(dtMessage);
                        myConnectionGroupData.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
            return dtMessage;
        }
    }
```

this is My BAL.

```
    public class ResponseBAL
    {
        public static DataTable ResponseMessage(string Message)
        {
            DataTable dtMessage = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                dtMessage = ResponseDAL.ResponseMessage(Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
            return dtMessage;
        }
    }
```

this my Controller

```
    public class ResponseController : ApiController
    {
        #region "Response"
        [Route("api/Response/ResponseMessage")]

        [HttpPost]
        public DataTable BranchList([FromBody]dynamic Data)
        {
            string Message = Data.Message;
            DataTable dtMessage = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                dtMessage = ResponseBAL.ResponseMessage(Message);
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {

            }
            return dtMessage;
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

I am sending a string as a input parameter and i should get a "SUCCESS" Message as my output in the postman collection...

Answer (score 0):

When you create the `SqlCommand` object, you need to supply the name of the stored procedure:

```
using (var myCommandGroupData = new SqlCommand(sprocName, myConnectionGroupData))
```

Alternatively, you can set [CommandText](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtext) after creating the object:

```
myCommandGroupData.CommandText = sprocName;
```